# Vue Router not routing to component

Tags: vue.js, routes, vite

I've created a simple application with a Vue Router with the code below

*App.vue*

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import MainHeader from './components/MainHeader.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="50" height="50" />

    <div class="wrapper">
      <MainHeader msg="Demo App" />

      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/test">Test</RouterLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>

<style scoped>
header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 2rem;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: var(--color-text);
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-left: 1px solid var(--color-border);
}

nav a:first-of-type {
  border: 0;
}

</style>
```

*TestView.vue*

```
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    Latest
    <RouterLink to="/test/article">Test Article</RouterLink>
  </main>
</template>
```

*TestArticle.vue*

```
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
    <div>
      <h1>things here</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

with this routing configuration

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
import TestArticle from '../articles/fakeArticle/TestArticle.vue';
import TestView from '../views/TestView.vue';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/test',
      name: 'test',
      component: TestView,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/test/article',
          name: "article",
          component: TestArticle,
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
})

export default router
```

However when I click on the routing URL to go to `/test/article`, the *TestArticle* component does not render. Instead, it stays displaying the *TestView* component.

I feel like I've tried all of the different combinations of paths but I still cannot seem to get it working. I'd appreciate any help I can get on this :)

Comment: You need a `RouterView` in `TestView` in order to display child routes. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes