# React Router Nested Routes not rendering child components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am doing some fairly nested routing using React router Dom in my React project. I can't seem to get my level of routes below the OrganizationView to show up. It was working before but added the OrganizationView route which seems to have broken every child/nested route. I do not have errors in my console, and my url is changing to what I expect it to, but it's not showing any of the routes downstream of OrganizationView. I'm removing many routes for simplicity, but if anyone can point at something obvious I'm doing wrong it would be very appreciated!

```
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      <Route path="" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route index={true} path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="/organizations/:organizationId"
          element={<OrganizationView />}
        >
          <Route
            path="/organizations/:organizationId/home"
            element={<Home />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/organizations/:organizationId/clients/:clientId"
            element={<ClientView />}
          >
            <Route
              path="/organizations/:organizationId/clients/:clientId/dashboard"
              element={<ClientDashboard />}
            />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
```

Comment: Does `OrganizationView` have an `<Outlet />`?

Comment: Oh my goodness. No it didn't. Thank you so much. Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested routing is not working in React Router v6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292641/283366). Funny enough, I encountered [almost the exact same issue for Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77526543/283366) earlier today

Comment: It did answer my question. thank you!